# How to migrate Wordpress Blogs into Multisite without using the GUI-Import/Export Feature

Tags: multisite, import, migration, export

I'd like to migrate some quite huge Wordpress-Blogs into one Multisite Installation.

The Export-Wizard and the Import Wizard are bound to PHP-Limits (Memory, Execution-Time) and so the Export and Import often fails.

There must be a way to do it by hand (only using MySQL and or the command line).

Comment: **Here it is - http://codesphpjs.blogspot.com/2016/05/migrating-normal-wp-site-as-multisite.html**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://bavatuesdays.com/importing-a-single-wp-blog-to-a-wpmu-installation/

http://sillybean.net/wordpress/migrating-single-wordpress-installations-into-multisite-networks/

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote this lately: http://wp.leau.co/2010/12/24/moving-a-weblog-to-a-wp3-multisite-weblog-system-on-mediatemple/ with a note for specific mediatemple take-care-things.

Comment: Link not working...