# Migrate site from WordPress multisite to another WordPress multisite

Tags: multisite, import, export

I'm wanting to migrate a site from one WordPress multisite install (Dev) to another (Staging). I've read these posts

[How to migrate Wordpress Blogs into Multisite without using the GUI-Import/Export Feature](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/how-to-migrate-wordpress-blogs-into-multisite-without-using-the-gui-import-expor) 
which is about migrating a single site (rather than a site in an existing multisite)

and this one
[Copy site from one multisite to another](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165486/copy-site-from-one-multisite-to-another)
which doesn't do a complete job (i.e. you have to deal with menus, etc separately).

Any improvements on either of these answers for migrating a site from one WordPress multisite install to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Search & Replace DB by Interconnect:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Using this tool will let you completely replace the URLs in the database and still maintain the entries as serialized data. This isn't specific to multisite but it should work the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

I know that just suggesting a plugin is not the best way to answer a question here, **however**....

I work extensively with multisite installations, and the most straight-forward way I've found is to use WPMUdev's 'Snapshot' plugin.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Manual is sometimes going to get you the best results however, have you looked at this plugin?

https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/multisite-clone-duplicator

I tend to use WPClone for single sites, if that fails then I use duplicator.

Let us know how you get on.